# How to open a mat-menu from another component using a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Hi guys i have two components both of them are siblings for that reason i need to use a service but i don't how to send the instance of the [MatMenuTriggerFor] to my another component.
Any help?

This is the code from one of my navBar.component where i have the logic to open my menu but from here .

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="categorias" [matMenuTriggerFor]="clickHoverMenu" #clickHoverMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"
          (mouseover)="openOnMouseOver($event)">
           Categorias 
            </a>
</li>
```

and this is the code of my slidebar component where i wanna open my menu

```
<mat-menu #clickHoverMenu='matMenu'>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: mat menu has a method openMenu that opens it. Simply get a reference in the containing component and make it available in a service, then call openMenu on it

Comment: Yeah it's what I've been thinking to do and even I've already created the service, i don't know how i can do it though.   i have no idea to take that reference.  So could you give to me an example , please? i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to establish the refrence to your `MatMenuTrigger`. You can accomplish this using `@ViewChild`. Then, you can `emit` the closing/opening with an `EventEmitter<T>`

Example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5gkff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomp2%2Fcomp2.component.ts)

**Service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyserviceService {
  public menuEmitter: EventEmitter<boolean>;
  constructor() {
    this.menuEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  }
  open(): void {
    this.menuEmitter.emit(true);
  }
  close(): void {
    this.menuEmitter.emit(false);
  }
}
```

**Then in any component you want to trigger the menu from:**

```
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {
  private readonly _myService: MyserviceService;
  constructor(myService: MyserviceService) {
    this._myService = myService;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  open(): void {
    this._myService.open();
  }
}
```

**Actual Component with MatMenu**

```
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {
  private readonly _myService: MyserviceService;
  @ViewChild('menuTrigger') matMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;
  constructor(myService: MyserviceService) {
    this._myService = myService;
    this._myService.menuEmitter.subscribe(this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  toggleMenu(state: boolean): void {
    this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
  }
}

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" >Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: But friend the button is in another component

Comment: That is what you asked. Two seperate components. One with MatMenu and the other invoking mat menu. Please upvote/mark as answer if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded">
```

Works for an expansion-panel. Same concept is true for menu.  Then [read this article for a centralized event service](https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech)